# Cable LAN connection issue

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, dns, dhcp, lan

I have booted Lubuntu 18.04.5 (try out mode from an USB stick, no proper installation) on an old netbook (HP Mini 210-3100) and ran into a LAN issue. First, wireless LAN access works as expected without any trouble (both DHCP and access DNS resolution).

Strangely, not so via the internal cable LAN - apparently DHCP works, an IP address gets assigned and other devices in the network can be reached via ping (using the IP address). It is even possible to reach the apparently correct DNS server (which works for other numerous devices in the network), but DNS itself seems not to work, as ping invocations such as

```
ping www.google.com
```

terminate with an error message indicating that name resolution does not work. The same internal cable LAN adapter works well under Windows. Any ideas? Please note that I'm not too familiar with Linux.

Calling

```
nmcli device show enp1s0f0
```

shows the correct DNS server in the

```
IP4.DNS[1]
```

property. Furthermore, using an external USB cable LAN adapter just works as expected.

Comment: FYI:  Lubuntu 18.04 LTS is no longer supported; refer https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/ or https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ where you'll note only Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop & Ubuntu Cloud come with 5 years of support; *flavors* had shorter lives. I'd suggest using `ubuntu-support-status` to assess the security status of your actual install. Your question is still on-topic here, but consider how much security matters to you and the results of prior command. You're now using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with LXDE (*not Lubuntu*).

Comment: Thanks for your comment; I was using Lubuntu because the netbook is very small (only 2 gigs of ram) which does not match the requirements for a "full" Ubuntu.

Comment: If you box was *i386* (32-bit x86, eg. intel atom n270) using 18.04 would make sense to me, but I'd opt for a more secure (*fully supported*) system but if you're only going to use it a few months fair enough as you know your actual end-use requirements.  I used devices as old as from 2005 in QA for all supported releases of Lubuntu (inc. with a 2GB RAM device; 1gb up to 19.04 with *i386*), but don't forget you're using the last LXDE release of Lubuntu which has no *release-upgrade* path, with 18.04 (EOSS) support April 2023.